# Take full and differential backup on secondary replica - SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, backup, sql-server-2014, availability-groups

I do have SQL Server 2014 high availability setup in Prod env.

> Server A – Primary, B-Secondary and C -DR.
>
> Server A to B are synchronous commit and automatic failover.
>
> Server A to C are asynchronous commit and manual failover.

I need to setup full-backup and diff backup. Can I do it on Server C?

I have given server C 98% priority in backup preferences – AG.

Running below query on server C but it throwing 1 which means I can't take backup on that server.

```
SELECT sys.fn_hadr_backup_is_preferred_replica (‘dbname’);
GO
```

Comment: Why would you want to take backups of a potentially out-of-date database?  Add more details about what you are attempting to do, and why.  Use the [edit] button.

Comment: we want to offload database backup which consumes I/O and CPU from prod primary server, is it possible to take backup on secondary?

Comment: is it possible to perform differential backup from primary and full and t-log from secondary in Always-On? Is there any data inconsistency issue while restoring these backups file?

Answer (score 1):

> I need to setup full-backup and diff backup. Can I do it on Server C?

You can do a copy only full, but unless C is the primary you cannot do a differential database backup.

> Running below query on server C but it throwing 1 which means I can't take backup on that server.

A return value of 1 means it is "preferred" but doesn't necessarily mean you can run *any* type of backup on it.